In the US, can I buy iPhone and Android phones and claim them as expense?
Let's say, if each year, I buy the top notch iPhone and Samsung phone, just to decide how to rebalance my US$500,000 investment in these two companies, are the cost of the phones tax deductible?
On the other hand, if I buy these two phones, and make YouTube videos, and they bring in $500 of income each year from YouTube, then are the cost of the phones tax deductible?
However, is it true that after 3 years, when the IRS and state tax board see that it is a business that loses money (the YouTube one), because the phones cost about $2000 and the revenue is $500, will then claim that such a business is more like a hobby and therefore disallow the tax write off for the future?

Are you using the devices exclusively for business purposes? If not, you need to document the time spent on business vs. other, and deduct accordingly. If so, then spending $2k to make $500 makes no sense.

Are you talking about business taxes or personal taxes? I think Trump's tax cuts got rid of deductions for personal finance expenses.

Surely you have been buying other products as well, say a Samsung container ship?

The IRS at least can disallow any deductions if they determine you are not trying to gain a profit (IRS Pub). I would argue that the case of buy a phone, "make" $100, and deduct full cost of the phone, would not be a valid business expense.

The IRS presumes that an activity is carried on for profit if it makes
a profit during at least three of the last five tax years, including
the current year...
If an activity is not for profit, losses from that activity may not be
used to offset other income. An activity produces a loss when related
expenses exceed income.

Your scheme is not trying to make money, but use a "loophole" to skirt taxes. The IRS does not like you skirting taxes...

but nobody knows how much money they can get from YouTube videos, or as a KOL. I am just using $500k and $500 to contrast the difference that $500k involvement may not allow you to buy a phone and claim as cost, but making a YouTube video can

@StefanieGauss I don't understand your comment. What does the $500k represent? What is "involvement"? If you're only deducting $1500 a year (2k-500) then sure, the IRS may not think it's worth the audit. But they might still notice and choose to investigate.

The IRS is highly attuned to people creating "hobby businesses" that don't make money and are really just intended as a screen to pay for people's hobbies or ordinary expenses.  They have a bunch of standards they use to determine whether or not a business is a good faith attempt at creating and running a profit making business. See the link @Nosjack provided. If all you did was create a YouTube video or rebalance your investment account they'd almost certainly deny the deduction, possibly with penalties. Claiming business deductions considerably raises your chance of getting audited.

Note also that the IRS only allows a deduction to the extent that the phone is used for business purposes. You'd have to figure out (and document) how much the phone is used for the business and how much is personal use. Only the portion associated with business use would be deductible.

@Stefanie The IRS recognizes that some businesses take a long time to get to profit (e.g. Tesla, Amazon took 10+ years to break even, and many "unicorn" dot-coms never do).  If you want to lose money for more than 3 of 5 years, there are 2 paths to do it: #1 present lots of data about comparable businesses showing your growth path is normal.  Or #2 be a farm.

@Charles agreed, in the "2 phones" example, I doubt IRS would want to hear that 60% of one phone and 70% of the other phone is business, unless your business was reviewing phones or something.  They would expect 1 phone to be 100% personal.

If you have business you can write off expenses that are necessary for the running of that business.  It is best to employ a tax adviser to understand best practices and what is allowable considering the kind of business you are running.
Your question suggests that you might want to buy a new phone each year and write it off on your taxes, but what happens to the old phone?  If a "top notch" phone is purchased, they are not normally obsolete within a year.
If those phones were sold, monies received would be revenue to the business.
Social media may claim that by merely opening a business all kinds of write-offs are available.  And while that may be partially true, there is also additional costs and labor to running a business, so many times such a strategy for the sole purpose of write-offs is a net loser.

This would all appear pretty quickly to be simply taking deductions that simply are not allowed.  If you are looking to rebalance your portfolios, allowable expenses are much more along the lines of subscriptions to research publications.  Since you are not claiming to be a professional investor, it is pretty limited.
I suppose I will ask you some questions that are rhetorical, but give you an idea of an absolute NO for your answer in scenario 1.

Would you buy a new computer - top of the line - and expense that for your
rebalancing activities? No, that one isn't going to fly, even if you log-in
with that specific computer.  No.
I don't mean this one as an insult, but would you claim the % of the house
expenses related to the single room you rebalance?  No.

The same applies for the iPhone.  Now if you subscrible to IBD, Barron's, and some other publications to help with investment choices, then not a problem.
Nothing passes the sniff test regarding the iPhone and it would come off as a pretty blatant unallowable Investment Expense.  You really would need a legit business as an active investor, as this is very passive. You have a depreciable item, yet cannot expense fully w/ section 179 or any other full/immediate writeoffs, not to mention, that phone has value at EOY, as was stated, so how do you account for that?  Offset expense with the sale proceeds?  Donate?  It's all irrelevant, since you are not a professional investor with the various requirements to be such.
I would say you need to be classified as a Professional Trader/Investor, who actively trades and marks to market gains & losses daily, thus avoiding wash sale rules. Now things are getting more promising.  But you would have to request to be considered an active/professional trader and approved, which makes phone more possible, but again, it's such a common mixed use item, unless you own a separate cell phone, I don't see this as a good idea in any event.
Scenario 2:
This absolutely falls under a hobby.  Attempting to write this off you would just be a game of "will I get audited", and if you do, lets say 5 years of doing such an activity is going to hurt bad.  It seems potentially blatant enough to be willful and then no statute of limitations potentially bringing so pretty hefty amounts due for the disallowed expense, interest, and any other penalties. This is worse-case scenario stuff, so in that case, I hope the years aren't adding up to high, as they all can become fair game AND you can bet prior years will be examined to maximize revenue/pay for audit fees/justify the resources.
In each case, the mixed-use would HAVE to result in a VERY LOW% on that phone, so you won't be writing off anywhere near the full cost, and I would imagine that if forced to prove the business portion, it would ultimately end up surprisingly low, making the opportunity cost of pondering, or even worse - taking the deductions - immaterial in the end.
Now, I have not been in accounting for a minute, but these are just various versions of extremely common tax avoidance methods that just aren't worth the potential penalties, and even then, if trying to keep as closely to all other rules, such as mixed use, you will not be writing off anywhere near $1,500 or $2,000.
